# (SPRING) From a simple form to a CRUD webapp - what to consider and what pitfalls to avoid?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, crud

I have been working on a Spring-mvc webapp that takes some form data and emails this accross to the administrator.

I wish to expand this webapp into a CRUD application. I have lined up some hibernate lessons and just need to do some work on my SQL skills before I start working on this.

What I need help with is the things to consider when expanding. The amount of work that will go into this means I cannot afford many mistakes when working on the foundations of this project.

The main component will be an admin panel that can work with submitted forms.

*+After this the system may be further developed by adding a user database where after each form completion a user would be created.*

**So really the main points of my question are:**

- Do I just go ahead and start designing the DB and learning Hibernate?
- Do I need to consider anything NOW if I wish to have user
  authentication down the line?
- Am I considering the most appropriate technologies? (Hibernate, mysql + Spring Security I presume for auth?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly you should learn how to design a database. Making huge changes on database after creating the application can lead serious problems.

You can set up spring security later. Just take look at [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/).

You can have an idea of hibernate implementation from [here](https://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial): a web application CRUD example shows how to integrate Spring MVC and Hibernate frameworks. Technology choice is appropriate (Hibernate, mysql + Spring)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can start my work now with less worries,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank's for your contribution. According the [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) we'd appreciate if you integrate the essential parts of code in your answer. High quality answers are more likely to get up-votes too. Thanks!